# OS X app menubar greyed out

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I'm running my app code on one computer and it works just like it should, the menubar is intractable. However, when I run it on another computer the menubar is greyed out. Both computers have OS X 10.10 and Xcode 6. Where might the error be? Some local setting or something?

[image]

Comment: What is this app for? is it require internet connection? or maybe you need to enable admin privileges or file access properties?

Comment: It does require internet connection, which both computers have. I've had the app run perfectly on both computers before, when I had Xcode 6 beta.

Comment: Is there any condition which menu items should satisfy to be enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the computer that caused issues was not running the latest version of Xcode (6.1) so I could not set the deployment target to 10.10. It was set to 10.9 and that caused the compatibility issues. Silly